# invalid ELF header when executing certain commands

Tags: raspbian

I installed a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian (without desktop) 4 weeks ago, that is running as a Nextcloud server with Docker. It has been ON since then, and is still ON. I connect to it remotely using SSH for admin tasks, and today I connected again and found that lot of commands and console applications are not working!

This is the problem I got when running a couple of commands I usually use for admin tasks:

```
$ top
top: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libprocps.so.6: invalid ELF header
$ htop
htop: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libncursesw.so.5: invalid ELF header
$ nano
nano: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libncursesw.so.5: invalid ELF header
```

Nothing changed, nothing got installed or altered since the last time I connected to it (which was about 2 weeks ago), and was working just fine.

Nobody else entered the Pi, already reviewed logs. Nextcloud is installed on Docker, and is still working. But now I'm afraid if I reboot the Pi or there's a power cutoff it won't boot again due to this error, since it seems to happen on some (let's say) "native" apps.

Raspbian is installed on a USB HDD, using the method officially documented by Raspberry (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md).

I can't neither do apt install, apt install --reinstall nor apt upgrade; when packages end downloading, I get this error (free translation):

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 file of files list from package libraspberrypi0 contains an empty file name
```

Real error (spanish):

```
dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:
 el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libraspberrypi0'
contiene un nombre de fichero vacío
```

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether your SDCard is failing or fake?

Comment: Dougie's suggestion is very good, checking if your SD works should be a first step. Here's an answer on [how to check for defective and fake SD cards](https://superuser.com/questions/631633/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-fake-sd-card)

Comment: @Dougie Raspbian is installed on a USB HDD, using the method officially documented by Raspberry (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md). However, I'm thinking it might be a HDD failure. Now the Nextcloud docker container stopped working saying something about an error on a layer... it seems like data corruption. I'm gonna get the HDD and do some checks.

Comment: @DavidLor, did you try running a normal, out-of-the-box Raspbian image while booting from a USB? Before assigning blame to data corruption, make sure that you followed the [steps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md) correctly. Even then, it is stated that booting from a USB is an experimental feature and does not always work, as documented [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/).